# Finding two smallest composite numbers

Tags: number-theory

Find two smallest composite numbers $n$, so that
$$2^n\equiv 2 \ \ \ (\text{mod }n)$$
$$3^n\equiv 3 \ \ \ (\text{mod }n)$$

I dont really know how to approach this problem. I could use some hints.

Comment: These are called pseudoprimes to base 2 and base 3, respectively.

Comment: Do you mean: "Find the smallest numbers $m,n$ that satisfy these equations $2^n\equiv 2\pmod n$ and $3^m\equiv 3\pmod n$" ?

Comment: Do you need the same $n$ to work for both equations simultaneously?

Comment: two different numbers $n$ that satisfy both equations

Comment: @user220972 I've found a solution to the simultaneous question: $n=561$.

Answer (score 1):

The small script

```
>> for n=2:1000
       if (modpow(2,n,n) == mod(2,n) && ... 
           modpow(3,n,n) == mod(3,n) && ...
           ~isprime(n))
           disp(n);
           break;
       end
   end
```

Gives $n=561=3\cdot 11\cdot 17$. `modpow` is an implementation of modular exponentiation.

For the single problems,
$$2^{341} \equiv 2 \pmod{341}, 341 = 11\cdot 31\\
3^6 \equiv 3 \pmod 6, 6 = 2 \cdot 3$$

Comment: We need composite $n$ to be composite. For prime $n$ how about $n=3$ ?

Comment: $2,3,5$ are not composite numbers

Comment: Not that it's very important, since we don't want primes, but $2$ and $3$ also satisfy the congruences simultaneously.

Comment: @user220972 I've found solutions now. Interesting how the solution of $3^n \equiv 3 \pmod n$ is so small compared to the solution of the other problem.